# Print dataframe without float precision

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to print a dataframe in my console without displaying any float decimal precision.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
pd_tmp = pd.DataFrame()
pd_tmp["new_column"] = [("a",2.01212121212),1.123123,8.1212]

print(pd_tmp)
```

The output I got after printing is:

```
0   (a, 2.01212121212)

1                1.12

2                8.12
```

Whereas what I expected is:

```
0            (a, 2.01)

1                1.12

2                8.12
```

There seems to be an issue to display the tuple without float precision. Any idea why ?

Cheers

Comment: `("a",2.01212121212)` is not a floating-point number but a tuple. It is not printed using `pd.options.display.float_format`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @DYZ, do you have any idea on how can we achieve the expected result (i.e. elements of  the tuple printed with no floating precision) ? Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this (very specific to this problem):

```
pd_tmp = pd.DataFrame()
pd_tmp["new_column"] = [("a", 2.01212121212), 1.123123, 8.1212]


def foo(pd_col):
    pd_new_col = []
    for i in pd_col:
        if not isinstance(i, float):
            lst = []
            for j in i:
                if not isinstance(j, float):
                    k = j
                    lst.append(k)
                else:
                    k = round(j, 2)
                    lst.append(k)
            pd_new_col.append(tuple(lst))

        else:
            pd_new_col.append(round(i, 2))

   return pd_new_col


pd_tmp["new_column"] = foo(pd_tmp["new_column"])
print(pd_tmp)
```

Output:

```
       new_column
0       (a, 2.01)
1            1.12
2            8.12
```